# Non-clustered index including columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Let's say I have table with many columns (20 for instance), and I often do the search by one of them. If I create non-clustered index for that column, then I know I should also include other columns from select statement to cover the query.

But what if the query is `SELECT *`, should I include all columns to index? I know I am making a copy of the whole table by doing that, is it good or bad practice?

Comment: "I know I am making a copy of the whole table by doing that" <- Does that sound like it will help you much?

Comment: @Lamak: Eish, harsh, dude...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing the most / whole table is not usually a good idea, especially if there are inserts / updates / deletes to the table. When all the wanted fields are not included in the index, a key lookup must be made using the clustered index to find the row(s) from the table. How good / bad that is depends on how many rows you're fetching and how many levels there are in the clustered index -- and that's why it's good to have a narrow clustering key, preferably an int.

If you have to do key lookups for significant portion of the rows in the table, it's usually a lot faster just to scan the whole table. That is most likely the case in your scenario too, because doing key lookups isn't going to be that expensive, if there's not much rows affected, so indexing all fields wouldn't really help.

Of course if your table is huge, indexing all the columns might help, at least in theory. I haven't ever even considered doing that, but I would assume it would help when scanning the whole table would be a costly operation. This of course only in case that the table doesn't get much updates, because maintaining the index would cause problems too.

Comment: This assumes you have a clustered index on the table, heaps behave slightly differently when it comes to lookups

Comment: Thanks for answer, there is only one thing which I don't understand. When non-clustered index seek is finished, I suppose we have a list of clustered-index ID-s, and then the key lookup is done for every of those ID-s. But why is this operation so expensive? What is the difference between these lookups and clustered-index seek?

Comment: You're doing a clustered index seek as many times as there are rows. One key lookup isn't bad, but a million key lookups might not be a good idea.